# D3 visualization does not starting

Tags: d3.js, visualization

Hi I am following a simple tutorial for my first D3 graph. I have downloaded the actual code given and when I try to open it in the browser there is definetly a placeholder for the visualization but the visualization does not appear. Any idea why?

This is the link to the tutorial and the html file is called force_connected.html

https://github.com/mohdsanadzakirizvi/d3js

Comment: you might have not run the code in your localhost

Comment: thankyou that was it!!